# Recommended way to represent my data with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on the processing of geologic data. Data is a 2D (x-y) map of vertical (z) columns of boxes, each box having more then 1 numerical parameter associated with it. I need the freedom to add/remove the box parameters as the code evolves (meaning I have no clue as of now how many I'd actually need). The number of boxes varies across the map. So the resulting 3D array is jagged in z direction. The algorithms applied to the data work on one vertical column of boxes at a time.

What would be a reasonable way to represent such a data structure using the numpy/scipy facilities? I've thought about a 3D structured array with a custom dtype. But it will potentially have lots of zeros because of the inherently jagged nature of the data.

Comment: If you don't know how many parameters you need, maybe you have to use dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is mutable during your code, `numpy` is not recommended.

A possible solution is to create a dictionary whose keys are the parameters. For example in a case with 2 boxes with coordinates `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]`, heights `h1` and `h2` and other *general parameters* you can define.

```
data = {
    'boxes': [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]],
    'height': [h1, h2],
    'general_parameter': [par1, par2]
}
```

in this way you can add parameters and boxes when you need:

```
data['new_parameter'] = [new_par1, new_par2]
```

if you want to use `numpy`, you can substitute `list`s with `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np

data = {
    'boxes': np.array([[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]),
    'height': np.array([h1, h2]),
    'general_parameter': np.array([par1, par2])
}
```

Comment: The reason I mention numpy is that I will typically have over a million of boxes to work with and iterative algorithms applied to them, so Python will likely choke unless I use the scientific stack.

Comment: if you have millions of boxes but few parameters this is a good solution.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. I'm gonna add an additional array to complement the `data` dictionary that will hold the number of boxes per column so that I can slice into the `data` values.